# get list of changed files in git without changes in merge commits

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the list of files (in branch 'dev') which were changed after the last push (in 'origin/dev'). However I don't want to get files, which were changed by merge from origin/master to dev. I guess I need behavior like git diff origin/dev --no-merges --name-status, but I can't find the suitable solution.

**For example:**

1. create file local_1 in dev branch
2. create file external_1 in master branch, commit&push to origin/master
3. commit local_1 in dev branch
4. merge origin/master to dev
5. create file local_2

I want to exec a command which will return local_1 and local_2 without external_1.

**My tries:**

I managed to find right commits by git log:

`git log origin/dev...dev --no-merges --first-parent --name-status`

It doesn't include files changed by merge. However there can be the case, when file was changed in the commit and in the next commit it was changed back. In this case I have this file in git log, so I guess I still need git diff or something else.

Comment: So, you actually want to answer the question "between `origin/dev` and `dev`, what are *my* changes?" This question can only be answered with a single diff when *all* commits between `origin/dev` and `dev` are yours. If you merge `origin/master` and you do not want to consider the commits that the merge introduces as yours, then there is no solution with a single diff.

Answer (score 0):

you can achive that by using both commandes :

1- to check merges done by other user into the checked branch :

```
git log --merges --first-parent --name-status
```

2- for other commits and changed files :

```
git log --no-merges --first-parent --name-status
```

But its always best to use a Git plugin in your IDE or use a  standalone program such as Sourcetree